# Can't connect VS2017 RC to mac agent

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.mac, visual-studio-2017

I had a configuration where VS 2015 was successfully connecting with Xamarin Mac Agent on same network.

I upgraded to VS 2017 RC & now the VS fails connecting to xamarin mac agent with error: "

> Couldn't connect to 'your-mac-name' Please try again

Nothing else in the configuration has changed.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had to upgrade the Mac to sierra, xcode to latest build available & also install latest versions of Xamarin.iOS for VS on Windows then it started connecting to mac again.

Comment: Do you use beta / alpha channel for Xamarin Studio? 
I cant get VS 2017 working with my macbook air. I updated to Sierra (10.12.3) , current XCode (8.2.1), Xamarin Studio 6.1, Xamarin iOS 10.3. 
A device with VS 2015 can connect but no iOS simulator devices are showing up in VS.